# virtualenv fails setuptools install error code 1

Tags: python-2.7, virtualenv, setuptools

I've been on the internet all day looking at various problems involving virtualenv with error code 1 and other info, and it seems none of them quite match my situation exactly, and I don't understand virtualenv enough to have any idea where to go. I apologize for the walls of text, but I am hoping someone can make sense of something in there.

### My Environment:

```
OS: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.1 (Santiago)
Global Python: /usr/local/bin/python (Python 2.6.6)
Local Python: /install/testuser/python7/bin/python (Python 2.7.1)
Virtulenv: /install/testuser/python7/bin/virtualenv (1.5.2)
User: testuser
Home: /install/users/testuser (i.e. not the working directory)
```

### My Process Thus Far:

```
wget http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.1/Python-2.7.1.tgz
tar -zxvf Python-2.7.1.tgz
cd Python-2.7.1
./configure --prefix=/install/testuser/python7
make
make install
cd /install/testuser/tmp
wget http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-1.5.2.tar.gz#md5=fbcefbd8520bb64bc24a560c6019a73c
tar -zxvf virtualenv-1.5.2.tar.gz
cd virtualenv-1.5.2/
/install/testuser/python7/bin/python setup.py install
mkdir /install/testuser/virtualenvs
cd /install/testuser/virtualenvs
```

### My Problem:

```
testlax08> /install/testuser/python7/bin/virtualenv testrun -v --python=/install/testuser/python7/bin/python2.7
Running virtualenv with interpreter /install/testuser/python7/bin/python2.7
Creating testrun/lib/python2.7
Symlinking Python bootstrap modules
Symlinking testrun/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
Symlinking testrun/lib/python2.7/config
Symlinking testrun/lib/python2.7/os.py
Ignoring built-in bootstrap module: posix
Symlinking testrun/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py
Cannot import bootstrap module: nt
Symlinking testrun/lib/python2.7/ntpath.py
Symlinking testrun/lib/python2.7/genericpath.py
Symlinking testrun/lib/python2.7/fnmatch.py
Symlinking testrun/lib/python2.7/locale.py
Symlinking testrun/lib/python2.7/encodings
Symlinking testrun/lib/python2.7/codecs.py
Symlinking testrun/lib/python2.7/stat.py
Symlinking testrun/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py
Symlinking testrun/lib/python2.7/copy_reg.py
Symlinking testrun/lib/python2.7/types.py
Symlinking testrun/lib/python2.7/re.py
Symlinking testrun/lib/python2.7/sre.py
Symlinking testrun/lib/python2.7/sre_parse.py
Symlinking testrun/lib/python2.7/sre_constants.py
Symlinking testrun/lib/python2.7/sre_compile.py
Symlinking testrun/lib/python2.7/warnings.py
Symlinking testrun/lib/python2.7/linecache.py
Symlinking testrun/lib/python2.7/_abcoll.py
Symlinking testrun/lib/python2.7/abc.py
Symlinking testrun/lib/python2.7/_weakrefset.py
Creating testrun/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Writing testrun/lib/python2.7/site.py
Writing testrun/lib/python2.7/orig-prefix.txt
Creating parent directories for testrun/include
Symlinking testrun/include/python2.7
Creating testrun/bin
New python executable in testrun/bin/python2.7
Changed mode of testrun/bin/python2.7 to 0755
Also creating executable in testrun/bin/python
Changed mode of testrun/bin/python to 0755
Testing executable with testrun/bin/python2.7 -c "import sys; print sys.prefix"
Got sys.prefix result: '/local/install/testuser/virtualenvs/testrun'
Creating testrun/lib/python2.7/distutils
Writing testrun/lib/python2.7/distutils/__init__.py
Writing testrun/lib/python2.7/distutils/distutils.cfg
No setuptools egg found; downloading
Installing setuptools...
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/s/setuptools/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg
Searching for setuptools
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/e3/6b/bb793ca610f364d1888b9bd7b83dccd0c27d779e4fd91a953ce8bae74996/setuptools-34.0.2.zip#md5=8e33d59407b6714e4e97274da538d08f
Running setuptools-34.0.2/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-L_ToWv/setuptools-34.0.2/egg-dist-tmp-Tr1OCR
/install/testuser/python7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'src_root'
warnings.warn(msg)
Traceback (most recent call last):
<Cut for space, seriously, it is long, available on request>
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
----------------------------------------
...Installing setuptools...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/install/testuser/python7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1649, in <module>
    main()
File "/install/testuser/python7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 558, in main
    prompt=options.prompt)
File "/install/testuser/python7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 654, in create_environment
    install_setuptools(py_executable, unzip=unzip_setuptools)
File "/install/testuser/python7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 384, in install_setuptools
    _install_req(py_executable, unzip)
File "/install/testuser/python7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 360, in _install_req 
    cwd=cwd)
File "/install/testuser/python7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 624, in call_subprocess
    % (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command /local/install/testuser/virtual...on2.7 -c "#!python
\"\"\"Bootstrap setuptoo...




" --always-copy -U setuptools failed with error code 1
```

### My Question:

Does someone know the issue I'm running into and how I can correct it? Constraints are that I have to work with Python 2.7, and that the original Python 2.6.6 cannot be disturbed.

#### Edit:

I have ruled out a few factors.

I tried installing multiple versions of setuptools, and that did nothing. I managed to separately install one of the versions of setuptools that was failing through, so it doesn't seem like a setuptools problem.

I also don't think it has to do with the Python version, although I'm less certain of this. pip seemed to install setuptools correctly at Python 2.7.1, but had other issues which prompted me to upgrade. Can't ever be sure though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Still no solution

I still have no idea about the problem, but I found a workaround. Less a workaround, I just attempted installation a different way and it worked.

### Workaround

First, I installed Python 2.7.13 instead of Python 2.7.1 so that I could support pip. Then I installed pip. By default, pip installs setuptools, so when I setup virtualenv, it didn't need to, and it worked fine. So the only change to my environment is the Python version, still stored in the same location: `Local Python: /install/testuser/python7/bin/python (Python 2.7.13)`

The process I used now includes installing pip:

```
wget http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.13/Python-2.7.13.tgz
tar -zxvf Python-2.7.13.tgz
cd Python-2.7.13
./configure --prefix=/install/testuser/python7
make
make install
cd /install/testuser/tmp
wget --no-check-certificate https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
/install/testuser/python7/bin/python get-pip.py
wget http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-1.5.2.tar.gz#md5=fbcefbd8520bb64bc24a560c6019a73c
tar -zxvf virtualenv-1.5.2.tar.gz
cd virtualenv-1.5.2/
/install/testuser/python7/bin/python setup.py install
mkdir /install/testuser/virtualenvs
cd /install/testuser/virtualenvs
```

I will pick this as the answer, but feel free to post if you know/find a better solution for the exact problem.